# Why is this producing a heap OutOfMemory error?

Tags: java

```
for(int i = 0; i < colorOrder.size(); i++)
    {
        String colour = "";
        colour = gui.getUserInputElement(i);
        userColourInput.add(colour);
    }
```

Basically I'm creating a "simon says" game, and I'm trying to move the data from an arrayList held in one class into an arrayList held in another class so that I can manipulate the data. colorOrder and userColourInput are arrayLists and the getUserInputElement() method is as follows:

```
public String getUserInputElement(int index)
    {
        return userInput.get(index);
    }
```

The error message I'm getting is:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

```
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458)
at Game.gameLoop(Game.java:87)
at Game.<init>(Game.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:746)
```

GameLoop is as follows, not sure which part is needed so hopefully its not too inconvenient if I post the whole thing.

```
public void gameLoop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        String input = "";
        boolean userInputFull = false;
        int inputSize = 0;

        if(orderPulled == false)
        {
            getColorOrder();
            System.out.println("colorOrder set to order ArrayList");
            userClicks = colorOrder.size();
            System.out.println("User clicks set to " + userClicks);
            orderPulled = true;

        }


        if(flashed == false)
        {
            pause(2000); //taking this out of here and putting in init or in this loop
        }                //causes a freeze, why?



        if(flashed == false)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < colorOrder.size(); i++)
            {
                gui.flashButton(colorOrder.get(i));
                System.out.println("Flashing " + colorOrder.get(i));
                pause(500);
            }
            gui.changeInstructionCopy();
            flashed = true;
            gui.enableButtons();
            System.out.println("colorOrder size: " + colorOrder.size());

        }

        inputSize = gui.getUserInputSize();

        if(inputSize == colorOrder.size())
        {
            gui.disableButtons();

            for(int i = 0; i < colorOrder.size(); i++)
            {
                String colour = "";
                colour = gui.getUserInputElement(i);
                userColourInput.add(colour);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            gui.enableButtons();
            gui.printUserInputArray();
        }







    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information here. We need to see more of the code. Particularly gameLoop, which is likely where the problem lies.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum runnable example?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I'll post it now. Edit: Posted.

Comment: Are you sure that userInput and userColourInput are not two references for the same array object?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you never clear `userColourInput`: you keep adding and adding elements to it in your `while (true)` loop until you run out of memory.

Comment: @Ajek: Delete elements from it. From what you've shown us, you just keep adding stuff until there's no more memory.

Comment: But all I need to do is add three elements from the userInput arraylist into the userColourInput arrayList. I'm using a for loop so I'm not sure how it adds more than three elements?

Comment: @Ajek: You run that three-element loop many many times, each time apparently adding a bunch of elements to the same `ArrayList`. Until you run out of memory. The list doesn't magically clear itself between the iterations of your `while (true)` loop.

Comment: Oh, goddamn. I've figured it out. I need a way to stop the if(inputSize == colorOrder.size()) loop from triggering after it's done it once.